# arcLength() and contourArea() return unexpected values

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to measure the length of a contour:

[image]

The green line is the HoughLineP computed on the contour. By computing the Euclidean distance on the green line, I get `153.88`. However, `arcLength()` on the contour gives `364.71` when it should be about 1/8 longer than the HoughLineP. How come `arcLength()` returns almost twice the length than the contour should be? Here's my code:

```
def euclid_distance(line):
    dx = line[0] - line[2]
    dy = line[1] - line[3]
    return math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)

_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contour = contours[1]
cnt_perimeter = cv2.arcLength(contour, False)

lines_p = cv2.HoughLinesP(mat_cnt, 1, np.pi/180, 30, minLineLength=10, maxLineGap=5)

line_dist = 0
for lp in lines_p:
    for l in lp:
        x1,y1,x2,y2 = l
        cv2.line(mat_cnt,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,200,0),2)
        line_dist += euclid_distance(l)
print cnt_perimeter, line_dist, contour.size
--
364.710676908 153.883072493 204
```

EDIT:

Here's the original contour:

[image]

Here are the points:

```
[[[386, 477]], [[385, 478]], [[378, 478]], [[377, 479]], [[373, 479]], [[372, 480]], [[368, 480]], [[367, 481]], [[361, 481]], [[360, 482]], [[355, 482]], [[354, 483]], [[348, 483]], [[347, 484]], [[342, 484]], [[341, 485]], [[336, 485]], [[335, 486]], [[329, 486]], [[328, 487]], [[324, 487]], [[323, 488]], [[317, 488]], [[316, 489]], [[311, 489]], [[310, 490]], [[306, 490]], [[305, 491]], [[299, 491]], [[298, 492]], [[293, 492]], [[292, 493]], [[287, 493]], [[286, 494]], [[279, 494]], [[278, 495]], [[275, 495]], [[274, 496]], [[269, 496]], [[268, 497]], [[263, 497]], [[262, 498]], [[255, 498]], [[254, 499]], [[249, 499]], [[248, 500]], [[241, 500]], [[240, 501]], [[220, 501]], [[219, 502]], [[216, 502]], [[219, 502]], [[220, 501]], [[240, 501]], [[241, 500]], [[248, 500]], [[249, 499]], [[254, 499]], [[255, 498]], [[262, 498]], [[263, 497]], [[268, 497]], [[269, 496]], [[274, 496]], [[275, 495]], [[278, 495]], [[279, 494]], [[286, 494]], [[287, 493]], [[292, 493]], [[293, 492]], [[298, 492]], [[299, 491]], [[305, 491]], [[306, 490]], [[310, 490]], [[311, 489]], [[316, 489]], [[317, 488]], [[323, 488]], [[324, 487]], [[328, 487]], [[329, 486]], [[335, 486]], [[336, 485]], [[341, 485]], [[342, 484]], [[347, 484]], [[348, 483]], [[354, 483]], [[355, 482]], [[360, 482]], [[361, 481]], [[367, 481]], [[368, 480]], [[372, 480]], [[373, 479]], [[377, 479]], [[378, 478]], [[385, 478]], [[386, 477]], [[390, 477]]]
```

As an aside, the contour area returned is `0.0` using the code below:

```
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 5, True)
print cv2.contourArea(approx)
---
0.0
```

How come the contour area is so small? The straight part is already 154 (length of HoughLineP).

Comment: Well, it's a contour, i.e. a polygon enclosing that line. Hence, I'd expect the circumference of the contour (which is what you're calculating) to be roughly 2x the length of that line, which it roughly is.

Comment: @DanMašek but in his code, flag `closed=False`: `cv2.arcLength(contour, False)` ..

Comment: Post your original image.

Comment: @Silencer Yeah, but the contour has 204 points, so the "not closed" bit probably makes a very small difference. A sample image to reproduce would definitely be useful.

Comment: @DanMašek But if the straight line is 154 in length, shouldn't the contour have at least 300 points? How do you determine that the not closed bit is small?

Comment: @Silencer The image I added is just the contour. The original image is actually Canny edges, so the contour in question is just one out of many. Unfortunately, I can't isolate and extract the edge. I've added the contour's points, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all lets put the problem to a simple test:

Lets create a line and calculate the euclidean distance and the arcLength.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

a = np.array([(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5), (6,6), (7,7)])

cv2.arcLength(a, False) # Prints 8.485281229019165
math.sqrt((7-1) * (7-1) + (7-1) * (7-1)) # prints 8.48528137423857
```

They are both (almost) equal....

So, what could be wrong? My only explanation is that your points are not in a line order or almost not in order.

For instance, lets add the point (0,0) which is in the line from the previous example to the end of the array.

```
a = np.array([(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5), (6,6), (7,7), (0,0)])
cv2.arcLength(a, False) # prints 18.38477635383606
math.sqrt((7-0) * (7-0) + (7-0) * (7-0)) # 9.899494936611665
```

As you can see, the arcLength increased by double... What is happening? The function actually does mini euclidean distance between the points... So, if you have a perfect line and in the correct order you will get the SAME result (or really close), but if one point is out of order, it may give something different.

Couple of remarks:

You get 153 with euclidean distance... then your line is thicker than 1 pixel in certain parts to get 204 points (thinking of at least 1 per pixel) This means that the contour could be detecting like 2 lines in the one line that you have and this means that you will get more perimeter.

You can try to do approx poly to get less points and see what is going on easily, or if you get the contour with findCountours, then you can use `CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` to compress it and see what is wrong with it.

I hope this clears your doubt, if not just leave me a comment.

Comment: I don't think the ordering of the boundary points is the issue. But how come you think the line is thicker than 1 pixel? Sure, there are more points in the contour than the length of the straight part, but aren't contours polygons? A polygon around a line should have more points than those on the line.

Comment: @JohnMunroe exactly my point, If you have a polygon around the line as contour, it will probably go either AROUND the line, or  zig zag perhaps... nevertheless you will have more length. Not always is a polygon, depends on how you found it, and if you compress it or something like that, but it is highly probable to be one... and then, each segment length added together will be more than the beginning/end length, for a polygon around a line it should be AT LEAST twice the size since you calculte the perimeter with it not biggest length.

Comment: But I checked `contourArea()` of the contour, it's `0.0` (please see edit). Shouldn't the polygon or whatever shape around the line have a positive area though?

Comment: @JohnMunroe maybe it is due to the approxPoly... try calculating the area without it

Comment: `contourArea(contour)` gives `0.0` as well. I should add that the original image is a Canny edge, so the contour wraps around a line. Not sure if it'd make a difference.

Comment: @JohnMunroe that one is a weird, can you share the contour points, in a way I can copy pasted to a python interpreter? just to give it a test :)

Comment: Sure. I've just pasted the output of `numpy.ndarray.tolist()`.

Comment: @JohnMunroe It seems that the contour is going over it back... so the area is 0... A line has area 0 too... (if you think height is calculated as ymax-ymin this will be 0 and 0xwidth = 0). You can try maybe to do MinAreaRect and get the height of it (the width is also available). Your contour its like 2 overlapping lines... thus twice the perimeter (it is similar to my toy example, just that you dont have only the 0,0 but all the other numbers as well repeated) remember OpenCV just adds segments of the distance between points...

Answer (score 2):

If you check the points in the contours one by one, you will find about half of them are the same.

The first ten:

```
[[257 113]  <-- 0
 [256 114]  <-- 1
 [249 114]  <-- 2
 [248 115]  <-- 3
 [244 115]
 [243 116]
 [239 116]
 [238 117]
 [232 117]
 [231 118]]
...
```

The last ten:

```
[[232 117]
 [238 117]
 [239 116]
 [243 116]
 [244 115]  
 [248 115]  <-- 3
 [249 114]  <-- 2
 [256 114]  <-- 1
 [257 113]  <-- 0
 [261 113]]
```

Check in picture:

[image]

You can find the points are `right-top` to `left-bottom` to `right-top`.

That is to say, although the contour represent a line, it's area is zero, but it is a `doubled line`, it's arclen is double of the distance found by hough.

Total `102` points, after do `set`, only `52` points leave.

If you know it's a line, then do `set`, then sort the `points in the set`, then calculate the arclen again, it won't be doubled.

---

Bad english.